# Accessing & Outputting $ElementalArea in Silverstripe 4

Tags: silverstripe, silverstripe-4

In a Silverstripe 4 project we have the following method under `PageController.php` for outputting the content of a page as JSON:

```
class PageController extends ContentController
{

 private static $allowed_actions = array(
     'json'
 );

 public function json(HTTPRequest $request)
 {
     $data = array();
     $data['ID'] = $this->ID;
     $data['Title'] = $this->Title;
     $data['Breadcrumbs'] = $this->obj('Breadcrumbs')->forTemplate();
     $data['Content'] = $this->obj('Content')->forTemplate();
     $this->response->addHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
     return json_encode($data);
 }
}
```

Now I would like to do the same thing with a page running the [Elemental module](https://addons.silverstripe.org/add-ons/dnadesign/silverstripe-elemental). Elementals allows page content to generated by a number of dynamic/ configurable blocks.

To access elemental I use the following template code: `$ElementalArea` - which returns generated HTML.

I need to replace the following line with one that returns the HTML generated by `$ElementalArea`:

```
$data['Content'] = $this->obj('Content')->forTemplate();
```

I'm not sure of the correct way to do this, any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exactly the same way - `$this->ElementalArea()->forTemplate()`.

Comment: This is the correct object relationship. However I had to use explicit casting so the JSON didn't try to handle it as an object: ```$data['Content'] = (string)($this->ElementalArea()->forTemplate());```